# Can I map a structure into a shared memory file?

Tags: c, struct, posix, shared-memory

I am trying to open a shared memory segment in my main process. My terminology may be incorrect in the question but this is what I am trying to achieve:

I collect information from 7 sensors and from that I evaluate the state. I made a structure `senStruct`. I want to share the 7 sensor and state information to other processes with use of shared memory. In code I am opening the `senfile`, mapping the `senStruct` into it. Now I simply want to store something into state and it gives me an error.

Here is the code:

```
#include <fcntl.h> /* Defines O_* constants */
#include <sys/stat.h> /* Defines mode constants */
#include <sys/mman.h>   
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

typedef struct senStruct {
    int sensor[7];
    int state;
}senStruct;

int main()
{
    int fd;
    size_t size = sizeof(senStruct);
    senStruct *p;
    fd = shm_open( "senfile" , O_CREAT | O_EXCL | O_RDWR, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR );
    ftruncate (fd, size);
    printf("Before mapping...p points to %p\n",p);
    p =(senStruct *) mmap (NULL , size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,MAP_SHARED , fd, 0);
    printf("After mapping...p points to %p\n",p);
    p->state=1;
    return 0;
}
```

Output is:

```
Before mapping...p points to (nil)
After mapping...p points to 0xffffffffffffffff
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Address of `p` after `p` seems doubtful to me. Looking into gdb indicates segmentation fault at `p->state = 1`. Is my procedure incorrect or did I miss anything?

Comment: The [`mmap` function](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/mmap.html) returns `-1` which means there was an error. You must remember to *always* check for errors.

Comment: Oh yes! You are right. I checked all the error code and I removed the O_EXCL flag in the shm_open and it is working. Thank you.